# Input values on the edit form are empty, using UI component- Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, edit, data-provider

This is my ui component file content:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_modulename_shippingmethods_form.shippingmethods_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">General Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="shippingmethods_form_data_source">
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\Modulename\Model\ShippingMethods\DataProvider" name="shippingmethods_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>entity_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Shipping Method Infomation</label>
        </settings>
        <field formElement="input" name="name" sortOrder="20">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and this is my DataProvider:

```
    namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ShippingMethods;

    use Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\ShippingMethods\CollectionFactory;

    class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
    {

        protected $_loadedData;

        public function __construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            CollectionFactory $employeeCollectionFactory,
            array $meta = [],
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->collection = $employeeCollectionFactory->create();
            parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        }

        public function getData()
        {
            if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
                return $this->_loadedData;
            }
            $items = $this->collection->getItems();
            .......
        }
    }
```

If I display my query string in the `getData()` with `echo $this->collection->getSelect();`, the result is:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mytable` AS `main_table` WHERE (`entity_id` = '') . My id is missing. Not sure how, any idea where to look ?  Thnx in advance
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They were empty because the `primaryFieldName` and  `requestFieldName` had wrong values. Instead of `entity_id` in my case i need to change it to simply `id`.

Answer (score 3):

A few things are playing together here.

## ✅ Overall

- `<requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>` is going to be what you have configured *(in your XML)* your URL Parameter to be when the user clicks *Edit* from the *Listing* UI Component *(aka. The Grid)*; it's what you see written in the web-browser's address bar.
- `<primaryFieldName>policy_id</primaryFieldName>` is generally not going to change and it will be the same as the column name in the MySQL database.

> **Note**: The example code herein came from a module that manages Content-Security-Policies so that's why you will see `policy_id` used. Your code will have something else there.

---

## How to **read** the URL parameter into the *Edit* form UI Component

> **Hint**: *For this functionality, we only care about `<requestFieldName/>`*

Make sure the following element matches whatever is showing-up as the URL parameter name in the web-browser's address bar:

###### `./view/adminhtml/ui_component/[your_component]_edit_form.xml`

```
<dataProvider class="..." name="...">
    <settings>
        ...
        <requestFieldName>policy_id</requestFieldName>
        ...
    </settings>
</dataProvider>
```

For example, look at the following two example URL parameters:

```
#1 https://local.domain.com/admin/csp/policy/edit/id/1/key/.../
#2 https://local.domain.com/admin/csp/policy/edit/policy_id/1/key/.../
```

> *☝️ the difference between those would correspond to these XML values, respectively:*

```
#1 <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
#2 <requestFieldName>policy_id</requestFieldName>
```

---

## How to **write** the URL parameter from the *Listing* UI Component

The **Edit** button on the *Listing* UI Component navigates the user to an *Edit* URL. To control what URL parameter name is placed in that URL, modify the following to have your desired URL parameter name within `<item name="urlEntityParamName" />` around here:

###### `./view/adminhtml/ui_component/[your_component]_listing.xml`

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="...">
    <columns>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="...">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">policy_id</item>
                    ...
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <indexField>policy_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

---

## A note about your Module's `DataProvider.php`

I don't believe people are making this mistake anymore but make sure your this file has at least this:

###### `.\Model\YOUR_OBJECT\DataProvider.php`

```
<?php
namespace YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\YOUR_OBJECT;

use YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\YOUR_OBJECT\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\PoolInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\ModifierPoolDataProvider
{

    protected $collection;
    protected $dataPersistor;
    protected $loadedData;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $yourCollectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = [],
        PoolInterface $pool = null
    ) {
        $this->collection = $yourCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data, $pool);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $_yourObject) {
            $this->loadedData[$_yourObject->getId()] = $_yourObject->getData();
        }

        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('your_object');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $yourObject = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $yourObject->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$yourObject->getId()] = $yourObject->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('your_object');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

> **Hint**: ☝️*Keep in mind that for `Factory` classes, you don't actually need to have a file named `YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\YOUR_OBJECT\CollectionFactory.php` you only need to have `YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\ResourceModel\YOUR_OBJECT\Collection.php` and Magento magic will take care of making the `Factory` reference work based on what you already have in `Collection.php`.*